# Sentiment analysis using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX) and Bluemix Services

Tags: ibm-cloud, data-science-experience, watson-studio

I’m trying to analyze customer feedback data (unstructured data) using IBM Data Science Experience (DSX) and Bluemix services. The objective is to do sentiment analysis.

1. Is it possible to call the Bluemix instances from DSX for this exercise? If yes, I’m looking for a sample Watson Machine Learning Flow.
2. Any alternative idea?

Comment: Read this article: https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/real-time-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-hashtags-with-spark-7ee6ca5c1585

Comment: Hi Deb, this type of question does not meet the stackoverflow criteria and is likely to get closed.  See here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In summary, [you should not be asking for code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) or [have open ended questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)